# How to do multiple columns of multiline braces in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, braces, cases

Just like `cases` environment, with a 2-line (or more) big curly brace to the left of some short equations - but I want to have 3 or 4 columns of equations across the page, each with left-brace.
So I can't have the brace outside the environment, I don't think, like the single-big-left-brace solutions I've seen with `aligned`/`array`/`cases` etc.
(Imagine 3 or 4 uses of 'cases' environment on a page, each with a large brace to the left of 2 or 3 short equations. What I want is like that, but with the cases/blocks 'stacked' horizontally instead of vertically.)

Sorry, if this has already been asked; I couldn't find it on here or online, and can't think how to do it. I just heard about `multicol`, maybe I'll have to use that, but it's surprising there seems no LaTeX/ams way of doing it. Thanks.

Edit: Ive been asked for an image. I tried without success, then I read that new users like me can't post them. Hopefully what I wrote is clear enough.

Comment: Without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), an image of expected outcome would really help. Pen and paper is really underestimated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also can use `dcases` from `mathtools` in an `align` or `alignat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  & \begin{dcases}
  x = 1\\
  y = 2 \\
  z = 8
  \end{dcases}
    & \qquad & \begin{dcases}
  x = t\\
  y = 2t \\
  z = 8t
  \end{dcases}
    & \qquad & \begin{dcases}
  x =2 t\\
  y = 5-t \\
  z = t²
  \end{dcases}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe using David Carlisle's `blkarray` package?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{blockarray}{\{l\{l\{l}
$x = 1$ & $x=t$ & $x=2t$ \\
$y = 2$ & $y = 2t$ & $y = 5-t$ \\
$z = 8$ & $y=3t$ & $z=t^2$
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Maybe you might play with the spacing between columns with `@{some space}`?

Answer (score 3):

My modified/stripped down plain-math-mode version of Bernard's alignat*/dcases answer, which (surprisingly) produces an identical result on my screen. Though his will obviously also align with further rows. (I'm using wordpress quicklatex)

```
\[
\begin{cases}
    x = 1\\
    y = 2 \\
    z = 8
\end{cases}      \quad 
\begin{cases}
    x = t\\
    y = 2t \\
    z = 8t
\end{cases}      \quad  
\begin{cases}
    x =2 t\\
    y = 5-t \\
    z = t^2
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: It should not be quite the same, since I use a double emspace between the cases, and you use one. You'll see a serious difference using `\frac{a}{b}` or `\int_a^b`, say. The `d` from `dcases` is for *\displaystyle*.